# PIMCORE : - "Block data type" field data migration through sql query issue

Tags: php, block, pimcore

As we know that in PIMCORE "Block Data type" get save in to a sigle column in "object_store_classID" table in serialized format.

I need to do data migration for "Block data type" field. As through pimcore object save it is taking too much of time, so I changed the approach and doing directly through sql query and saving serialized data directly in to table.

All the data get saved in specified format(serialized) in to "object_store_classID" table through sql queries but block field data not getting visible on frontend (Pimcore admin interface). I saved  Data in to "Store" and "dependencies" table.

Can anybody help me to identify If I am missing anything here or any dependent tables related to "Block data type" field?

Thorugh Pimcore admin interface, If I am saving any data in "Block data type" field it is getting saved in to single column in serialized format and visible to frontend (admin interface).

However same seriazed format data if I am copying from above object and saved in to other object directly in to Table, it is not visible on frontend (Admin interface).

Hope I am clear with my points!